# wav to aac conversion interruptListener not calling in ios

Tags: ios, audio, aac, avaudiosession, interrupt-handling

I am doing an audio based app in which i am converting a wav file to aac format. Conversion working successfully but interrupt listener not called while conversion even if one call came... I am initialising audioSession and handling interruption in main(). Interruption listener working in another part of application like recording and playback. Anyone can help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution for this problem. I had used audioSession category

> kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback

earlier for AAC Conversion. Now I changed it to

> kAudioSessionCategory_AudioProcessing

So it is working good now. Interruption listener method is called perfectly while interruption takes place.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem solve it out by this , U can read This Link: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html

Comment: thank you for the link.. I have read but couldnt find the solution.. I am using hardware codec for the  conversion.  where to check that extfilewrite errors for interruption? Currently i checking that before the buffer fileWrite. But not called when interruption occur... Any idea?

Comment: When a call is coming while conversion whole process got stucked and also not calling interrupt listener..